# Android: How to disable the sound of all third-party apps' notifications from code?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile, notifications

I need to disable all sounds of third-party apps' notifications from code.

Something like this: when the app is open - all notifications from all apps are silent. When the app closes - the sound settings return to what they were before.

How to implement it? Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager) is what you are looking for.

You can access it like that (called inside an Activity in this example):

```
val audioManager: AudioManager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
```

To get the current volume (so you can restore it at a later point), use

```
audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION)
```

When your app starts, you mute the notifications by calling

**for SDK < 23**:

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 0, 0)
```

**for SDK >= 23**:

```
audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, 0)
```

Note as per official docs:

> From N onward, volume adjustments that would toggle Do Not Disturb are
>   not allowed unless the app has been granted Do Not Disturb Access.

As mentioned is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43127589/1199662), you'll need to declare `ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY` and actively request access.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, very useful! 
In addition there was a need to add ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY request, the Karl Johan Vallner's answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123650/android-request-access-notification-policy-and-mute-phone helped to do it.

Comment: glad I could help. I have updated the answer to reflect this info.