# Android application set to SilentMode onStart of the applicaion

Tags: java, android, audio

My intention is to make my software set phone in silent mode `onStart()` of the application, and set media (the phone speaker) volume to 0 by default;

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)MainPage.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (audioManager != null) {
            audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        }
```

Am I doing it correctly ? Please do correct me.

Comment: What is issue?.

Comment: yes you are correct... better use context. See my solution below :)

Comment: android studio gave me this message : ```java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.johnmelodyme.BSC/com.johnmelodyme.BSC.MainPage}: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to change Do Not Disturb state```

Comment: Use permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />

Comment: Now I got this  : ``` Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to change Do Not Disturb state```  for my ```audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);```

Comment: Finally worked guys, I dont know how, I sync with gradle , it worked! Thanks <3

Answer (score 1):

try below code hope this help -

```
    AudioManager am;
    am= (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if(am != null){
    //For Silent mode
    am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
}
```

Dont forget to add permission in menifest file -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are doing it correctly but there is a change from Android M, read [Android request ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY and mute phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123650/android-request-access-notification-policy-and-mute-phone) .

---

If you want to improve the above code *(but add code to support M and above)*, then you can modify it like

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if (audioManager != null) {
    int currentMode = audioManager.getRingerMode();

    if (currentMode != AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) {
        // Make ringer mode silent
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
    }
}
```

And make sure that you are using permission in manifest as this setting will require `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />`.