# How to setStreamVolume on STREAM_NOTIFICATION to value, gives java.lang.SecurityException

Tags: java, android, volume, android-audiomanager

I am not able to solve this Security Exception, please help:

---

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity (ActivityThread.java:5567)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity (ActivityThread.java:5597)
  at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute (DestroyActivityItem.java:44)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState (TransactionExecutor.java:190)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:105)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2386)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:213)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8178)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:513)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1101)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:2071)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2039)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1987)
  at android.media.IAudioService$Stub$Proxy.setStreamVolume (IAudioService.java:2180)
  at android.media.AudioManager.setStreamVolume (AudioManager.java:1193)
  **at sk.alfa.alias.VoiceControl.muteAudio (VoiceControl.java:253)**
  at sk.alfa.alias.MainActivity.onDestroy (MainActivity.java:289)
  at android.app.Activity.performDestroy (Activity.java:8350)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy (Instrumentation.java:1348)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity (ActivityThread.java:5552)
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: 
  at com.android.server.audio.AudioService.setStreamVolume (AudioService.java:2530)
  at com.android.server.audio.AudioService.setStreamVolume (AudioService.java:2359)
  at android.media.IAudioService$Stub.onTransact (IAudioService.java:947)
  at com.android.server.audio.HwAudioService.onTransact (HwAudioService.java:1057)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal (Binder.java:1028)
```

---

Problem is in row VoiceControl.java:253 - audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, actVolume,  0); :

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

static int REQ_CODE_NO_BEEPS = 1;

requestDoNotDisturbPermission();


private void requestDoNotDisturbPermission() {
    if(audio.getVolumeFixedPolicy()) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        if (notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
            StaticUtils.save(context,"volume_policy",true);
        } else {
            StaticUtils.save(context,"volume_policy",false);
        }
    }else{
        StaticUtils.save(context,"volume_policy",true);
    }
}

if(!StaticUtils.getBool(context,"volume_policy")){
                    volumePolicyText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    volumePolicyText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // Ask the user to grant access
                            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, MainActivity.REQ_CODE_NO_BEEPS);
                        }
                    });
                }





@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == MainActivity.REQ_CODE_NO_BEEPS) {
        if(audio.getVolumeFixedPolicy()){
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            assert notificationManager != null;
            if (notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
                StaticUtils.save(context,"volume_policy",true);
            }
        }
        volumePolicyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

}

public VoiceControl(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    audio = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    assert audio != null;
    actVolume = audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}

public boolean getVolumeFixedPolicy(){
    volumeFixedPolicy = audio.isVolumeFixed();
    return volumeFixedPolicy;
}

public void muteAudio(Boolean muted){
    boolean notificationValid = true;
    if(getVolumeFixedPolicy()){
        if(!StaticUtils.getBool(context,"volume_policy")){
            notificationValid = false;
        }
    }
    if(notificationValid){
        if(muted){
                audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, AudioManager.FLAG_VIBRATE);
                audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_MUTE, AudioManager.FLAG_VIBRATE);
        }else{
                audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, actVolume,  0);
                audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.ADJUST_UNMUTE, 0);
                audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, actVolume, 0);
                audio.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_UNMUTE,0);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here in function muteAudio I am using also solution to fixedvolume policy, where I added to manifest
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>`.
When it is needed programatically unmute I need to set specific volume for NOTIFICATION.
Some devices throw these RuntimeExceptions and SecurityException, what is wrong ?

Comment: By the looks of it, you're trying to mute notifications, which on Android N and later requires the user's permission. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43127589/1524450

Comment: When you look at bottom Notification policy is OK, StaticUtils.getBool(context,"volume_policy") is true where I used exactly code from your link... I did not attached code for this.So another problem it must be

Comment: Then you should add that code to your question, because it's relevant. Also, the only time you ever call `StaticUtils.getBool(context,"volume_policy")` is if `isVolumeFixed` is true. You should always make sure `isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted` is true before calling any methods that requires it.

Comment: I added clear coding from MainActivity, please check now.

Comment: Like I said, you need to make sure that `isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted` returns true before trying to mute notifications, but right now you only do that when `isVolumeFixed` is true.